# map does not name a template type for custom struct

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a simple object:

```
struct TimeObject {
    private:
       UInt64 m_currentTime;
       bool m_isStarted;
}
```

This object is utilized in a map in another struct:

```
std::map<Utf8String, TimeObject> m_myMap;   // *
```

and instantiated in the constructor of the struct:

```
m_myMap = new std::map<Utf8String, TimeObject>();
```

It seems to say that the definition (where the * is ) causes the following error:  ***Error: 'map' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type***

The first part of the question is: Understanding the error.  When you understand that you can work to resolve it.  My first guess would be that the struct *TimeObject* is created in the same file, and its definition is not defined at the time this line is compiled so it throws an error.  This occurs even though the struct was not declared IN the other struct, but as follows:

```
struct TimeObject{}
struct MyNewObject
{
    private: std::map<Utf8String,TimeObject> m_myMap;
}
```

So what is this particular error scream about?  Should i define TimeObject inside of the struct so it understands?

Comment: Did you `#include <map>`?

Comment: I thought that if i did absolute path definitions via `::` that it wasnt needed?

Comment: After I added it, it says:   Error TimeObject was not declared in this scope.

Comment: @Fallenreaper did you `#include` the file where struct TimeObject is defined?

Comment: @selalerer its in the same file, though not defined inside of each other, but instead defined like the bottom quote of my question

Comment: @Fallenreaper the extract at the bottom should work, providing `Utf8String` is declared in scope.

Comment: Thats what i was thinking too, but got this error:  `Profiler.h:71:25: error: 'TimeObject' was not declared
in this scope
std::map <Utf8String, TimeObject> m_myMap`

Comment: You should write a new question detailing the new issue with an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You are missing a semicolon after TimeObject{} (and also after the MyNewObject struct b.t.w.). `struct TimeObject{}; struct MyNewObject { private: std::map<Utf8String, TimeObject> m_myMap; };`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to `#include <map>`. If you write `using namespace std;`, or `using std::map;` then you don't need to qualify the name, but the compiler still needs to know where to find the declaration.

Comment: Ahh, thats what i was thinking.  I thought i did `using namespace std` which makes sense.  Ok, i included map, but there is a second part of this question that i would be curious in resolving